How to get pd.Dataframe from ClickHouseHook()?
I got this code in my DAG for Airflow:
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import io
import httpx
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from airflow.models import Variable
from clickhouse_driver import Client
from airflow_clickhouse_plugin.hooks.clickhouse import ClickHouseHook
from airflow.models import Connection
from airflow.utils.db import create_session


default_args = {
    'owner': 'd-chernovol',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'retries': 2,
    'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(minutes=5),
    'start_date': datetime.datetime(2024, 6, 20)
}
schedule_interval = '*/20 * * * *'
host = Variable.get('host')
database_name = Variable.get('database_name')
user_name = Variable.get('user_name')
password_for_db = Variable.get('password_for_db')
bot_token = Variable.get('bot_token')
chat_id = Variable.get('chat_id')
connections_name = 'clickhouse_default'
try:
    # create Connection
    clickhouse_conn = Connection(
        conn_id=connections_name,
        conn_type='ClickHouse',
        host=host,
        schema=database_name,
        login=user_name,
        password=password_for_db,
        port=8443
    )
    # create connection
    with create_session() as session:
        session.add(clickhouse_conn)
        session.commit()
    # make ClickHouseHook
    ch_hook = ClickHouseHook(clickhouse_conn_id=connections_name)
except:
    ch_hook = ClickHouseHook(clickhouse_conn_id=connections_name)

@dag(default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=schedule_interval, catchup=False, concurrency=3)
def test_dag_4():
    @task
    def get_table_from_db(sql_query):
        result = ch_hook.execute(sql_query)
        return result

    @task
    def send_msg(bot_token: str, chat_id: str, message: str):
        # send_message
        url = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{bot_token}/sendMessage?chat_id={chat_id}&text={message}'
        client = httpx.Client()
        return client.post(url)

get_table_from_db_task >> send_msg_task
st_dag = test_dag_4()

My code is working, but get_table_from_db(sql_query) returns:
class 'airflow.models.xcom_arg.PlainXComArg'>

If I convert result to string I get list with values from table:
[[111, 'name_1'], [222, 'name_2'], [222, 'name_3']]

But I need to get table from my database as pandas.Dataframe.
How I can achieve it? Or I should write function for this?
The main problem, that I get only values without column names.

According to
https://clickhouse-driver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#clickhouse_driver.Client.execute
and
https://github.com/bryzgaloff/airflow-clickhouse-plugin/blob/master/src/airflow_clickhouse_plugin/hooks/clickhouse.py#L88
you can't pass with_column_types=True from ClickHouseHook to clickouse_driver
so you need to create PR or issue in https://github.com/bryzgaloff/airflow-clickhouse-plugin/issues

Hm , I can pass "with_column_types=True" to ClickHouseHook. Now I can create DataFrame.

I make simple function to get pandas.DataFrame from tuple I get by ClickHouseHook:
def convert_sql_result_to_df(result: tuple):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=result[0], columns=[c for c, _ in result[1]])
    return df

